How to switch profiles with aws configure sso without having to clear browser cache
These are the steps I need to currently follow in order to switch profiles with aws configure sso from my terminal to use aws cli commands without credentials missing error:

Set default browser to one I don't use OR clear browser cache

aws configure sso --profile X
(If browser cache cleared, it requests sign in and password, otherwise it seeems to default to previous signed in user)

aws configure list
(It hasn't set my profile, so credentials are missing!)

export AWS_PROFILE="X"
fixes this

aws configure list
( It should now show both profile selected and credentials filled)


Now it works, but if I want to switch profile I have to go through all those steps. Is there a better way, where all I have to do is:
aws configure sso --profile newprofile?
I'm using latest aws cli on windows in vscode terminal

I dont think I fully understand the question, but if it helps, have you take a look at manually configuring using the config file?

@Gin The question is how to make aws configure sso --profile actually work. Since it doesn't!

as far as i understand, aws configure sso --profile means you want to execute the command using specified profile already in your credential file, not specifying which profile you want to configure

I'm voting to reopen, because on-topic questions for SO include "or software tools primarily used by programmers" (it's right there in the close-vote reason), and AWS is definitely a tool primarily used by programmers

The only way I solved this was:

aws sso logout
aws sso login --profile admin
signin via browser
export AWS_PROFILE="admin" (Without this step, it will not work!)

aws sts get-caller-identity
It still requires 4 steps, including having to export AWS_PROFILE, but at least I don't have to clear my browser cache.
